# Help understanding Logarithmic property in the proof to Big O problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics

Here is the problem:

> A sorting method with “Big-Oh” complexity O(n log n) spends exactly 1
> millisecond to sort 1,000 data items. Assuming that time T (n) of
> sorting n items is directly proportional to n log n, that is, T (n) =
> cn log n, derive a formula for T (n), given the time T (N ) for
> sorting N items, and estimate how long this method will sort 1,000,000
> items.

Here is the solution:
[image]

Here is the part I don't understand:

> Ratio of logarithms of the same base is independent of the base, hence, any appropriate base can be used in
> the above formula (say, base of 10).

I don't know what exactly does that mean. I researched the property but not much has made it clear. How came it's the same base, if it's upper case N vs lower case n?

Thank you.

Comment: It means that $\frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)}$ stays constant no matter what you choose for the base.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the formula for base change:

$\begin{align*}
  x
    &= b^{\log_b x} \\
  \log_a x
    &= \log_b x \cdot \log_a b \\
\end{align*}$

From this:

$\begin{align*}
  \log_b x
    &= \frac{\log_a x}{\log_a b}
\end{align*}$

That is all they are saying.